# PHP function - works outside function, but not inside

Tags: php, function

I have the following PHP code, which is stored in a seperate PHP file to the index.php file I am using.

The page include()'s fine into the index.php file when not within a function.

```
  $_3_dart_score = $_POST["user-input"];
  $remaining_score = 501 - $_POST["user-input"];
```

However when it is included with an function, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
function throw()
{
$_3_dart_score = $_POST["user-input"];
$remaining_score = 501 - $_POST["user-input"];
global $_3_dart_score
global $remaining_score
throw();
}
?>
```

I have tried all sorts, even calling the function from the index.php page, however nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your function is calling itself which I highly doubt you want

Comment: Fair point. I will try again with a loop. Thanks

Comment: You don't really want a function accessing global variables like that. Pass them is as arguments, like:  function throw($input, $otherinput) {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `throw()` from outside of your function, not inside of it. You should also consider passing variables as arguments instead of relying on global variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
function throw($input) {
    $_3_dart_score = $input;
    $remaining_score = 501 - $input;
    return array($_3_dart_score, $remaining_score);
}

list($_3_dart_score, $remaining_score) = throw($_POST["user-input"]);
```

1. Get rid of the `global` nonsense. That's bad form. Instead return those values. I use an array so I can return both at once. (They actually should be done separately in different functions but you're not quite there yet).
2. I pass `$_POST["user-input"]` as a parameter to `throw()` as your function should not be so closely tied to other code. This way that value can come from anywhere and this function will still work.
3. I use `list()` to put those values in the array into there own scalar variables in a one-liner.